# .htaccess CORS headers not working

Tags: .htaccess, cors

I've added the following at the top of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

In order to allow a subdomain-served login screen to do an AJAX Request to the main domain. It works on localhost, but not on the actual server. I've googled around quite a lot but there doesn't seem to be a solution for this. I've already checked through SSH if apache mod_headers was loaded, and the LoadModule line is there on the httpd.conf file.

Comment: When you have access to the httpd.conf file please don't use .htaccess files but place your desired settings in the main httpd.conf https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Any error? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled?

Comment: @MrWhite I already tested removing the IfModule but there was no difference nor errors. There's no override line in `.htaccess`

Comment: The appropriate `AllowOverride` directive needs to be set in the _server config_ before these directives in `.htaccess` will do anything.

Comment: @MrWhite I've checked and the AllowOverride directive is there. Also, other directices in .htaccess work properly.

Comment: @HBruijn I've put the same content in the httpd.conf and tested, but it still doesn't work. I've checked with Google Extension 'Tamper', and I could see that in localhost the headers are indeed being set, but not in the actual sever.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that might be removing these headers? Have you tried just setting a "test" header such as `X-Test` - is that set? Have you tried removing the `always` condition? Or tried using two directives with and without the `always` conditon, as noted in the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header Any difference in config/version between the local development server and the live environment?